# How to define a global variable in a busy ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, throttling

In my site, I call a third party API. To avoid hitting its rate limit, I need to define a global variable to enqueue requests. *([I'm using `RateLimiter`](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/RateLimiter) any better solution?)*

```
namespace MySite.App_Start
{
    public static class Global
    {
        public static int MaxCount { get; set; } = 30;
        public static TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        private static TimeLimiter rateLimiter;
        public static TimeLimiter RateLimiter
        {
            get
            {
                if (rateLimiter == null)
                    rateLimiter = TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(MaxCount, Interval);

                return rateLimiter;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'll use `RateLimiter` property. But I've read a lot that having a global variable is not a good idea. Considering my site has a lot of requests per second, is my code safe to use? Thanks.

Comment: Well, in `c# ` there is no such thing as a global variable, so...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto isn't? ummm my property `RateLimiter` has a global value that is shared across all the requests.

Comment: That is a static value, not a "global" one

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ok thanks. By any chance aren't you an academic who cares a lot about terminology? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't 100% safe since it could create multiple instances of TimeLimiter in the beginning and depending on surrounding code, it could be a problem. I'm guessing it wouldn't be a big problem, but it's better to write the code properly to begin with.

This is something an IoC container handles nicely, but if you don't want to use one, you could use Lazy:

```
private static TimeLimiter rateLimiter = new Lazy(() =>
    TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(MaxCount, Interval));
public static TimeLimiter RateLimiter => rateLimiter.Value;
```

Comment: I searched about IoC but ended up with lots of complicated open tabs. do you suggest one IoC container?

Comment: But I think I'm going with `Lazy` and TimeLimiter

Comment: Most of them aren't that different if you don't deep dive into specific things. But I would suggest Autofac since I think it has sane choices, good features and is continuously maintained to handle new things like .NET Core etc.
And it also has a good nuget package for ASP.NET MVC (both core and pre-core)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can make it thread-safe by using *lock* statement.

```
public static class Global
{
    public static int MaxCount { get; set; } = 30;
    public static TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    private static object _lockObject = new object();
    private static TimeLimiter rateLimiter;
    public static TimeLimiter RateLimiter
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                if (rateLimiter == null)
                    rateLimiter = TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(MaxCount, Interval);
                return rateLimiter;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since performance was important here, if you're using lock, I would suggest using [double checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) to avoid contention.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not thread-safety.
Try this:

```
public class Singleton
{      
  protected Singleton() { }
  private sealed class SingletonCreator
  {
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }
  }
  public static Singleton Instance
  {
    get { return SingletonCreator.Instance; }
  }
}
```

Or use your favorite IoC-container with creating SingleInstance object

Comment: Is this any different than my implementation? (I didn't down vote and hate when people do it without explanation)

Comment: 2 @Blendester : There is a difference. When you use construction 'if (rateLimiter == null)' in multi-thread code you can get nullReference exception, becase one thread begin init RateLimiter property, but not ends. Other property can get not-completly inited value.